ASP.NET Core Identity Login User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Always Returns False
I’m trying to implement login functionality using ASP.NET Core Identity, and everything seems to be working fine. The PasswordSignInAsync method returns "Succeeded", indicating the login is successful. However, after login, the following check always returns false:
var isLogin = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

LoginFrom.cshtml:
@page
@model Navedehsas.Pages.Account.LoginModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ورود به سایت";
    Layout = "Shared/_AccountLayout";
}
<div class="form-content">

    <h1 class="">فرم ورود</h1>
    <p class="">برای ادامه به حساب کاربری خود وارد شوید</p>

    <form class="text-left" method="post">
        <div class="form">

            <div id="username-field" class="field-wrapper input">
                <label for="username"> <span class="text-danger">*</span> نام کاربری</label>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-user"><path d="M20 21v-2a4 4 0 0 0-4-4H8a4 4 0 0 0-4 4v2"></path><circle cx="12" cy="7" r="4"></circle></svg>
                <input id="username" asp-for="Command.Username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="نام کاربری">
                <span asp-validation-for="Command.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div id="password-field" class="field-wrapper input mb-2">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
                    <label for="password">رمزعبور</label>
                    <a href="auth_pass_recovery_boxed.html" class="forgot-pass-link">رمز عبور را فراموش کرده اید؟</a>
                </div>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-lock"><rect x="3" y="11" width="18" height="11" rx="2" ry="2"></rect><path d="M7 11V7a5 5 0 0 1 10 0v4"></path></svg>
                <input id="password" asp-for="Command.Password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="رمزعبور">
                <span asp-validation-for="Command.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" id="toggle-password" class="feather feather-eye"><path d="M1 12s4-8 11-8 11 8 11 8-4 8-11 8-11-8-11-8z"></path><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="3"></circle></svg>
            </div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-between ">
                <div class="field-wrapper">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="">ورود</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-between pt-2">
                <div class="field-wrapper">
                    <div class="social">
                        <a asp-page-handler="ExternalLogin" asp-route-provider="Google" id="google-signup" class="btn social-google">
                            <img src="~/adminthem/assets/img/google__g__logo.svg" alt="Google Icon" class="google-icon" />
                            <span class="brand-name">ورود با گوگل</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="social pt-2">
                <a asp-page-handler="ExternalLogin" asp-route-provider="Facebook" class="btn social-fb">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-facebook"><path d="M18 2h-3a5 5 0 0 0-5 5v3H7v4h3v8h4v-8h3l1-4h-4V7a1 1 0 0 1 1-1h3z"></path></svg>
                    <span class="brand-name">ورود با فیسبوک</span>
                </a>
                <a asp-page-handler="ExternalLogin" asp-route-provider="GitHub" class="btn social-github">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-github"><path d="M9 19c-5 1.5-5-2.5-7-3m14 6v-3.87a3.37 3.37 0 0 0-.94-2.61c3.14-.35 6.44-1.54 6.44-7A5.44 5.44 0 0 0 20 4.77 5.07 5.07 0 0 0 19.91 1S18.73.65 16 2.48a13.38 13.38 0 0 0-7 0C6.27.65 5.09 1 5.09 1A5.07 5.07 0 0 0 5 4.77a5.44 5.44 0 0 0-1.5 3.78c0 5.42 3.3 6.61 6.44 7A3.37 3.37 0 0 0 9 18.13V22"></path></svg>
                    <span class="brand-name">ورود با گیت هاب</span>
                </a>
            </div>

            <p class="signup-link">حساب ندارید؟ <a asp-page="Register"> یک حساب کاربری ایجاد کنید</a></p>

        </div>
    </form>

</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("form").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                var formData = $(this).serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    method: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        debugger
                        if (response.isSucceeded) {
                            notify(response.message, 'success')
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                window.location.href = "/";
                            }, 1000);
                        } else {
                            notify(response.message)
                        }

                        //$("#spinner-overlay").hide();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        console.log("خطا در ارسال درخواست: " + error);
                        $("#spinner-overlay").hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    </script>
}

LoginFrom.cshtml.cs:
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(LoginDto command)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return Page();

    var result = await accountService.LoginAsync(command.Username, 
        command.Password, command.RememberMe);

    return new JsonResult(result);
}

AccountService.cs:
public async Task<Result> LoginAsync(string emailOrUsername, string password, bool rememberMe)
{
    var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(emailOrUsername) 
               ?? await FindUserByEmailAsync(emailOrUsername);

    if (user == null)
        return Result.Failed("Invalid username or password");

    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName ?? string.Empty, password, rememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

    return result.Succeeded ? Result.Succeeded("Login successful") : Result.Failed(result.IsLockedOut ? "Account locked" : "Invalid username or password");
}

In the Program.cs, I have the following configurations:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Navedehsas.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using Navedehsas.Data;
using Navedehsas.Services;
using Serilog;

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .CreateLogger();

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    var configuration = builder.Configuration;
    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    builder.Host.UseSerilog().ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
    });

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger();
    var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("navedehsasConnection");
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(option =>
    {
        option.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
    });

    builder.Services.Configure(connectionString);
    var app = builder.Build();

    using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var permissionService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPermissionService>();
        await permissionService.AddAllPagesPermissionsAsync();
    }

    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        // app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseRequestLocalization();
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.MapRazorPages();
    app.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "اجرای اپلیکشن با خطا  مواجه شد.");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}

Configure
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets;
using Navedehsas.Core.Application;
using Navedehsas.Core.Services;
using Navedehsas.Core.Services.Interfaces;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;
using System.Text.Unicode;
using Navedehsas.Utilities;
using WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore8;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Navedehsas.Core.AutoMapper;
using Navedehsas.Data;
using Navedehsas.Data.Entities;
using CustomRequestCultureProvider = Navedehsas.Utilities.CustomRequestCultureProvider;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text.Json;
using SharedResource = Navedehsas.Utilities.SharedResource;
using Navedehsas.Core.Dto.Base;
using AutoMapper;

namespace Navedehsas.Services
{
    public static class Configuration
    {
        public static void Configure(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(option =>
            {
                option.Filters.Add<PermissionFilter>();
            }).AddRazorPagesOptions(opts =>
            {
                 opts.Conventions.AuthorizeAreaFolder("Admin", "/", "AdminOnly");
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy =>
                    policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            });

            #region localization

            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options => options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (t, f) => f.Create(typeof(SharedResource)));

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new[]
                {
                    new CultureInfo(CultureType.Dari),
                    new CultureInfo(CultureType.English),
                    new CultureInfo(CultureType.Pashto),
                };
                options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture: CultureType.English, uiCulture: CultureType.English);
                options.SetDefaultCulture(CultureType.English);
                options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                options.FallBackToParentCultures = true;
                options.FallBackToParentUICultures = true;
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider());
            });
            #endregion

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 200 * 1024 * 1024;
            });

            services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 209715200;
            });

            #region IOC
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.AddScoped<IFileUploader, FileUploader>();
            services.AddScoped<ISliderService, SliderService>();
            services.AddScoped<IBlogService, BlogService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthHelper, AuthHelper>();
            services.AddScoped<IBlogMemoryCashService, BlogMemoryCashService>();
            services.AddScoped<IBlogQueryService, BlogQueryService>();
            services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();
            services.AddScoped<IPermissionService, PermissionService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICourseService, CourseService>();
            services.AddScoped<ICourseQuery, CourseQuery>();
            services.AddScoped<ILanguageService, LanguageService>();

            services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDataProtection();
            services.AddSingleton(HtmlEncoder.Create(UnicodeRanges.BasicLatin, UnicodeRanges.Arabic));
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(SliderMappingProfile));
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(BlogMappingProfile));
            services.AddScoped<ISharedResourcesServices, SharedResourcesServices>();

            services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders().AddRoles<Role>().AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrors>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 3;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
            });

            #endregion

            #region External Login

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                        {
                            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        })
                        .AddCookie(options =>
                        {
                            options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                            options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Register?handler=logout";
                            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                        })
                .AddFacebook(options =>
                {
                    options.AppId = "";
                    options.AppSecret = "";
                    options.Fields.Add("picture");
                })
                .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
                {
                    googleOptions.ClientId = "";
                    googleOptions.ClientSecret = "";
                    googleOptions.CallbackPath = "/signin-google";
                    googleOptions.UsePkce = false;
                    googleOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
                    googleOptions.Events.OnCreatingTicket = context =>
                    {
                        var picture = context.User.GetProperty("picture").ToString();
                        context?.Identity?.AddClaim(new Claim("picture", picture ?? ""));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    };
                }
               ).AddGitHub(options =>
               {
                   options.ClientId = "";
                   options.ClientSecret = "";
                   options.CallbackPath = "/ExternalLoginCallback";
                   options.Scope.Add("user:email");

                   options.Events.OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                   {
                       var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                       request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                       var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request);
                       response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                       var user = JsonDocument.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                       var avatarUrl = user.RootElement.GetProperty("avatar_url").GetString();
                       if (context.Identity != null)
                           if (avatarUrl != null)
                               context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("urn:github:avatar_url", avatarUrl));
                   };
               });

            #endregion
        }
    }
}

Where is the problem?
The PasswordSignInAsync method returns a success result, which means the login is successful, and the user has entered the system.
However, this is not the case; the login is not completed, and I cannot access pages that require login.
Even when debugging manually, the login has not been completed.
In the browser's cookies, a cookie named .AspNetCore.Identity.Application is added, which is of the session type.
Despite this setup, the user is not authenticated after login. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?

Do you have a full [mre] you can post somewhere?

@GuruStron  I have included all the relevant parts of the code related to the issue. If there's anything specific you need, please let me know so I can add it.

Naved, please excuse me for my laziness but personally I would like to have a full snippet that I can just run and spare me some time guessing the full setup.

@GuruStron No problem, I’ll edit my code and provide a complete snippet for you to run. Thanks for your patience!

@GuruStron I updated the question; please take a look at it.

looks like you have some schemes there that use bearer token instead of cookie... maybe check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes#code-try-7


    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Register?handler=logout";
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                })


The issue relates the above code.
Using the above code, you are setting the default Authentication method to Cookie-Based authentication without Identity, in this scenario, in the login post method, you have to use the HttpContext.SignInAsync() method to store the user principal into cookie.
await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity), 
        authProperties);

More detail information, see Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity.
If you want to use Identity as the default authentication scheme, try to modify the DefaultAuthenticateScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme as below:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Register?handler=logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
})

Both the above methods should solve the problem. Since you are using multiple Authentication scheme, you can refer to this article to set specific scheme: Authorize with a specific scheme in ASP.NET Core.

After troubleshooting, I resolved the issue by removing the following configuration in Configuration  related to cookie authentication:
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Register?handler=logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

Once I removed this section, my login functionality started working correctly, even with Ajax requests.
